# finding github repo working directory in desktop

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, github

I'm using continuous integration to run tests, which depends on my GitHub repository. The repo is structured into folders, with code in one folder and tests in another. I need to access code in code folder to run my unittests. How do I change the working directory to the code folder for the test files when online in GitHub (I have a separate branch just for the continuous integration)?

Comment: Depending on which CI provider you are using, switch folder in the CI/CD configuration file

Comment: how do I do that? I am using CircleCI which has YAML files

Comment: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run

Comment: ok so the problem I'm having is finding the working directory for my code folder. I've run the os.cwd() command and the directory changes with each run.

Comment: What you are trying to do is import stuff from your source to your test modules?

Comment: Are you using `pytest` or similar?